# Flask test_client returns 405 error using flask_restful

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

My Flask app code looks like this

```
#!flask/bin/python
import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from werkzeug.serving import WSGIRequestHandler
import logging
from flask import Flask, request
from waitress import serve

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='ui', static_url_path='')


def create_app():
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    logger = logging.getLogger('webapp')
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    WSGIRequestHandler.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"
    app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

    CORS(app, origins=['http://127.0.0.1', 'http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:3000/api'],
     allow_headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"], supports_credentials=True)

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '...'
    app.config['JWT_ACCESS_LIFESPAN'] = {'hours': 24}
    app.config['JWT_REFRESH_LIFESPAN'] = {'days': 30}

    jwt = JWTManager(app)

    api = Api(app)

    api.add_resource(resources.Login, '/api/login', methods=['POST'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
    # app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, use_reloader=False)
```

My testcase looks like this

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = app.test_client()
    self.client.testing = True
    result = self.client.post('/api/login/', content_type='application/json',
                              json={'email': 'tester@fairxchange.co.uk', 'password': 'Tyle82654isMid!'})

    json_data = json.loads(result.get_data(as_text=True))
    self.token = json_data['access_token']
```

result has:

```
<Response streamed [405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED]>
```

I have simplified the code here. in the TestCase setUp I used the api/login to collect the jwt token before using it in each of my test cases. But am not getting pass the login.

Where am I going wrong? The Flask app works fine outside testing.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same exact issue and saw the issue that you opened. I was stuck on it for several days and then on a whim I replaced the endpoint with the full URL and it worked. All of my endpoints were working fine with the test client but not the POST endpoints.

So for example, I had this originally and received [405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED] no matter what:

```
res = test_client.post('/api/v1/some-endpoint', json={'some': 'json'}, headers=some_header, follow_redirects=True, content_type='application/json')
```

This is what fixed it for me:

```
res = test_client.post('https://<my server>.com/api/v1/some-endpoint', json={'some': 'json'}, headers=some_header, follow_redirects=True, content_type='application/json')
```

I do not know why all my other endpoints work fine with the endpoint alone. The POST tests seem to need the entire URL.